# How to Save sender Email Details with attachment In SharePoint 2016 List Using workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

For Example:-

We have a email Id like info@abc.com. so if any user send email to info@abc.com so 
I want All sender email information save in SharePoint List with details like  Attachment,Subject,content.

Give me need full information.How to achieve this?

Many Many Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list or library that accepts emails and have a rule in your exchange that forwards the email to the SharePoint list whenever someone sends the email to info@abc.com.  I would suggest using a discussion board for it.  They seem to handle emails well.  You should be able to get most of the information you are looking for.  You will only get user infomration if the user is part of your SP farm's AD.